# AngularJS: Call AngularJS function inside a form tag by using ng-submit directive

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

This is my AngularJS function that I want to call in my form tag

[image]

This is my html form that I call my function in ng-submit but it is neither redirecting nor performing any action
[image]

I don't know where I am wrong, but nothing happens when I click on button.

Comment: Question is not clear

Comment: check the console?

Comment: See images @Cyril

Comment: Yah...i check console @Icycool

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: ah ok if you are using `ng-submit`, remove `type=button` in your button or use `type=submit`

Comment: Okay..i'll try @Icycool 33

Comment: Please avoid adding images of the code. Please add code here.  @Urvi_204

Answer (score 0):

Simple make button type equals "submit" which will call the function defined in ng-submit.

Comment: Okay.. @Shubham Tripathi

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the **type** attribute from the button tag.

```
<button class="btn" id="addbtn" ng-disabled="email_type.$invalid">add</button>
```